# Referencing the next entry in RDD within a map function

Tags: apache-spark

I have a stream of `<id, action, timestamp, data>`s to process.

For example, (let us assume there's only 1 id for simplicity)

```
id     event         timestamp         
-------------------------------
1      A             1                 
1      B             2                 
1      C             4                 
1      D             7                 
1      E             15
1      F             16
```

Let's say `TIMEOUT = 5`. Because more than 5 seconds passed after D happened without any further event, I want to map this to a `JavaPairDStream` with two key : value pairs.

```
id1_1:
A             1                 
B             2                 
C             4                 
D             7
```

and

```
id1_2:
E             15
F             16
```

However, in my anonymous function object, `PairFunction` that I pass to `mapToPair()` method,

```
incomingMessages.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, RequestData>() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Tuple2<String, RequestData> call(String s) {
```

I cannot reference the data in the next entry. In other words, when I am processing the entry with event `D`, I cannot look at the data at `E`.

If this was not Spark, I could have simply created an array `timeDifferences`, store the differences in two adjacent timestamps, and split the array into parts whenever I see a time difference in `timeDifferences` that is larger than `TIMEOUT`. (Although, actually there's no need to explicitly create an array)

How can I do this in Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still struggling to understand your question a bit, but based on what you've written, I think you can do it this way:

```
  val A = sc.parallelize(List((1,"A",1.0),(1,"B",2.0),(1,"C",15.0))).zipWithIndex.map(x=>(x._2,x._1))
  val B = A.map(x=>(x._1-1,x._2))
  val C = A.leftOuterJoin(B).map(x=>(x._2._1,x._2._1._3 - (x._2._2 match{
case Some(a) => a._3
case _ => 0
})))
val group1 = C.filter(x=>(x._2 <= 5))
val group2 = C.filter(x=>(x._2 > 5))
```

So the concept is you zip with index to create val A (which assigns a serial long number to each entry of your RDD), and duplicate the RDD but with the index of the consecutive entry to create val B (by subtracting 1 from the index), then use a join to work out the TIMEOUT between consecutive entries. Then use Filter. This method uses RDD. A easier way is to collect them into the Master and use Map or zipped mapping, but it would be scala not spark I guess.

Comment: Thank you, but a tuple represents a user action, and I am basically creating a new different session for a user when user has not been active for a certain amount of time (which I refer to as `TIMEOUT`). Thus in my example, if `TIMEOUT=2`, I want to map (A, B, C, D, E , F) into ((A, B), (C), (D), (E, F))

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you need:

```
def splitToTimeWindows(input: RDD[Event], timeoutBetweenWindows: Long): RDD[Iterable[Event]] = {
    val withIndex: RDD[(Long, Event)] = input.sortBy(_.timestamp).zipWithIndex().map(_.swap).cache()
    val withIndexDrop1: RDD[(Long, Event)] = withIndex.map({ case (i, e) => (i-1, e)})

    // joining the two to attach a "followingGap" to each event
    val extendedEvents: RDD[ExtendedEvent] = withIndex.leftOuterJoin(withIndexDrop1).map({
       case (i, (current, Some(next))) => ExtendedEvent(current, next.timestamp - current.timestamp)
       case (i, (current, None)) => ExtendedEvent(current, 0) // last event has no following gap
    })

    // collecting (to driver memory!) cutoff points - timestamp of events that are *last* in their window
    // if this collection is very large, another join might be needed
    val cutoffPoints = extendedEvents.collect({ case e: ExtendedEvent if e.followingGap > timeoutBetweenWindows => e.event.timestamp }).distinct().collect()

    // going back to original input, grouping by each event's nearest cutoffPoint (i.e. begining of this event's windown
    input.groupBy(e => cutoffPoints.filter(_ < e.timestamp).sortWith(_ > _).headOption.getOrElse(0)).values
}

case class Event(timestamp: Long, data: String)

case class ExtendedEvent(event: Event, followingGap: Long)
```

The first part builds on [GameOfThrows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4291805/gameofthrows)'s answer - joining the input with itself with 1's offset to calculate the 'followingGap' for each record. Then we collect the "breaks" or "cutoff points" between the windows, and perform another transformation on the input using these points to group it by window.

NOTE: there might be more efficient ways to perform some of these transformations, depending on the characteristics of the input, for example: if you have lots of "sessions", this code might be slow or run out of memory.